# Making page not (reload) when the function is toggled? READ

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to fix this issue I'm having.  I am trying to get it so when a user clicks the login button, it will make the `<div>` drop down.  The `<div>` does drop down, but the page teleports to the top of the page when you click the button.  And that's an issue for me.

So can anyone fix this code to make it so the page doesn't teleport up every time they press the LOGIN button?

Thanks for all help in advance~

Here is the link to the code - http://jsbin.com/oyujoy/4/edit

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oyujoy/3/   There it is!  Sorry, didn't post earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Change your link from:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">LOGIN</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">LOGIN</a>
```

See: http://jsbin.com/apudem/1/